# Repetir una función con distinto resultado en Js

Tags: javascript, web

tengo un código que quiero que repita una función 50 veces con distintos resultados pero al hacerlo repite la misma función y me entrega el mismo resultado 50 veces.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
let dado1 = (Math.round(Math.random() * 4) +1);
let dado2 = (Math.round(Math.random() * 4) +1);
let resultado = dado1 + dado2


let vecesLanzar = 50
    for(i=1;i<=vecesLanzar;i++){
      function LanzarDados(){
        console.log(`Dado 1 = ${dado1}`)
        console.log(`Dado 2 = ${dado2}`)
        console.log(`El resultado de la suma de ambos es: ${resultado}`)
      }
      LanzarDados()
    }
```

Como podría hacer para que al reptarse la función me entregue distintos resultados? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes de hacer es llamar a la función aleatoria cada vez que ejecutas, lo que hace el código que has puesto es llamar a dos funciones aleatorias e imprimirlas 50 veces en lugar de ejecutar la función 50 veces.

```
function LanzarDados(){
//llama a la función aleatoria cada vez que lanzas los dados.
  let dado1 = (Math.round(Math.random() * 4) +1);
  let dado2 = (Math.round(Math.random() * 4) +1);
  let resultado = dado1 + dado2

 //incluye la impresión dentro de la función
  console.log(`Dado 1 = ${dado1}`) 
  console.log(`Dado 2 = ${dado2}`)
  console.log(`El resultado de la suma de ambos es: ${resultado}`)
}

let vecesLanzar = 50
for(i=1;i<=vecesLanzar;i++){         
  LanzarDados()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución más rápida que se me ocurre es que metas la función random dentro del `for` para que por cada ciclo que haga calcule un nuevo resultado.

```js
var dado1; 
var dado2; 
var resultado; 
let vecesLanzar = 50

//Sacamos la función del ciclo
//E incluso podemos meter todos los cálculos dentro de la función.
function LanzarDados() {
    dado1 = (Math.round(Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    dado2 = (Math.round(Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    resultado = dado1 + dado2
    console.log(`Dado 1 = ${dado1}`)
    console.log(`Dado 2 = ${dado2}`)
    console.log(`El resultado de la suma de ambos es: ${resultado}`)
}
        
for (i = 1; i <= vecesLanzar; i++) {
    // Aquí solo mandaremos a llamar a la función
    LanzarDados()
}
```

Saludos.